# 1080p30 DVI to Flash Player

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, video, video-streaming, video-capture

I have a high-definition video camera which outputs 1080p30 video over a DVI (yes, DVI) cable. Somehow, I need to use this video in a software prototype written with Flash using ActionScript 3. Any thoughts on how to do this?

Right now, I am putting the DVI into a Folsom ImagePro HD and getting composite out to a Pinnacle Dazzle, which in turn is used as a webcam in the Flash Player. This process forces interlacing once the video hits the Dazzle, since the Dazzle only supports 480i. The interlacing looks really bad, especially at one point where I need the video to scale down.

Comment: *More information please:* What platform are you running on?  OS? Available expansion ports?  (FW, PCI, etc.)  There will have to be a hardware component to your solution, which is a starting point.

Comment: Currently running on Windows XP, but can switch to anything that runs Flash Player 10+. I am very open to any type of hardware, software, etc that needs to be acquired.

Comment: The machine we're using now is a Shuttle XPC with 1 of 2 PCI-e slots available. The PC has a Matrox M9120 in the used PCI-e slot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
Apply smoothing to video before scaling it down. This reduces the harsh lines caused by interlacing.

Answer (score 0):

I think your only option is to use somekind of bridge to get the camera to show up as a webcam. It might also be possible to do some sort of local streaming solution, maybe using [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/).

Comment: Would VLC be able to connect to video taken in from a capture card?

Comment: i think so, download it and try!